# Format color of shiny datatable (DT) according to values in a different dataset

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to format the DT according to the values from the previous table. 
For example, I want to display if something 
has increased, decreased or remained the same. 
I could do this with kable but 
could not get the next step where I want to clik a the cell and show all the data related 
to that value in another DT.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("iris_head")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  #df_data <- iris

  df_data <- head(iris[-5])

  # Just a dataset describing if iris has changed over a month
  # If reference data is of the same size as the original data (df_data). 
  # If reference data is negative I want the cell in the df_data to be green; 
  # If zero blue and if positive then green.
  # I can make changes with ranges within the current range, can we get the color encoding from another table?
  # set the seed
  set.seed(42)
  reference_df <-  (sapply(df_data, function(x) jitter(x, amount = 2)) - df_data) %>% 
    round(. , digits = 0) 

  print(reference_df)


  output$iris_head <- renderDataTable(datatable(df_data, selection = "single" )%>%
                                        formatStyle('Sepal.Width',
                                                    color = styleInterval(c(3.4, 3.8), c('green', 'blue', 'red')),
                                                    backgroundColor = styleInterval(3.4, c('gray', 'yellow'))) %>%
                                        formatString('Sepal.Width', suffix = '<font color="red">&uArr; </font>'))


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The `reference_df` in this case is:

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
        2           1            2           0
        2          -1           -1           0
       -1           1            0           2
        1           1            2          -1
        1           0            2           2
        0           1           -2           2
```

The required output is shown in the Figure where I also want to color the text and if possible the background according to values in reference_df.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the text color part, you could do it with `formatStyle` but you would need to `cbind` the `df_data` and `reference_df`, then pass it to `datatable` and change the style of columns 1 to 4 based on the value of columns 5 to 8:

```
datatable(cbind(df_data,reference_df), selection = "single",
                                                options=list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(5:8)))))%>%
                                        formatStyle(1:4, valueColumns=5:8,
                                                    color = JS("value < 0 ? 'red' : value > 0 ? 'green' : 'blue'"))
```

The columnDefs part hides the last 4 columns.

You can't `formatString` based on values so if you want to add the arrows, you could modify `df_data` to add the colors and arrows before passing it to `datatable`:

```
  for(col in 1:dim(df_data)[2]){
    df_data[col] <- mapply(function(i,j){
      ifelse(i > 0, paste0("<span style='color:red'>",j,"<font>&uArr; </font></span>"),
             ifelse(i<0, paste0("<span style='color:green'>",j,"<font>&dArr; </font></span>"),
                    paste0("<span style='color:blue'>",j,"<font>&hArr; </font></span>")))
    },reference_df[col],df_data[col])
  }

  output$iris_head <- renderDataTable(
    datatable(df_data, selection = "single",escape = F)
    )
```

This loops through the values of `df_data` and changes them depending on the values of `reference_df`. You need `escape=F` as an argument in the `datatable` call to prevent HTML escaping.

You can add more CSS styling in the `span` tags if you want to color the background etc.

Comment: Thanks! for a very well explained answer. Little odd that someone downvoted this question without a comment considering the fact that it received such a good answer.