# Render a colored arrow next to a value using data table in R

Tags: r, dt

**Edit:** Don't know how to close my own question but found a workable approach here:
[Format color of shiny datatable (DT) according to values in a different dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569302/format-color-of-shiny-datatable-dt-according-to-values-in-a-different-dataset)

I know that this question has been asked and [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59901826/add-an-indication-arrow-inside-dt-cell-which-will-show-trend-for-each-time-perio) in relation using `formattable` but I'm wondering if a similar solution exists using `datatable`.

I have a table which shows both negative and positive numbers.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
set.seed(5)

data.frame(x = sample(seq(-100, 100), 100, replace = T)) %>% 
  datatable
```

I would like a green up-arrow alongside the positive numbers and a red down arrow alongside negative numbers as shown below:

[image]

Can anyone tell me if this is possible when the table exists as a data table?

Answer (score 1):

I hope the answer still helps you....
yes that is possible.

In detail, depending on whether the value is positive or negative, I simply paste the corresponding icon in front of the value.I include the icon via the `fontawesome` library.

It is important to set the parameter `escape = FALSE` in the call `datatable()`, so that the html elements are rendered accordingly.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(fontawesome)
set.seed(5)

x <- sample(seq(-100, 100), 100, replace = T)
data <- data.frame(x = x)
data[which(x > 0), 1] <- paste0(fa(name = "arrow-up", fill = "green"), data[which(x > 0), 1])
data[which(x < 0), 1] <- paste0(fa(name = "arrow-down",fill = "red"), data[which(x < 0), 1])

datatable(data = data, escape = F, options = list(
  columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-right', targets = "_all"))
))
```

[image]